# Add label and button to a UICollectionView xcode 9, swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uilabel

**I have created a label in a UICollection view which is scrolling horizontally.**

> 1. I need to provide data to display on that label on runtime by satisfying some conditions.
> 2. By tapping on that label it should filter the data from the table view and display it in the same table view

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjFt.png)

CODE:

```
let xxx = ["Appointments", "Waitlisted", "Suspended", "Billing", "Cancelled", "Transfer", "Revoked", "Checkedin"]
// This dummy count data should be provided in the runtime by satisfying some condition, just to check I have created a compile time value
    let dummyCount = ["5", "10", "2", "3","6","1", "5", "2"]

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return xxx.count
        return dummyCount.count

    }
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "statusDisplayCell", for: indexPath) as! statusDisplayCollectionViewCell
        cell.countOfStatusCell.text = dummyCount[indexPath.row]
        cell.xxxCell.text = xxx[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has you stuck? Please cut, paste and format your code into your question. You'll have more success getting help.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, Sorry, I have posted the code as answer @ Mozahler

Comment: No. Your code is not an answer.  Please delete that. Click 'edit' on your first answer and paste the code there. Welcome aboard!! 